# Bootstrap not pulling right

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to learning bootstrap and I have just finished my 'navbar'.

I am very stuck though, whenever I try to pull-right for my un ordered list, it just stays in the middle? Please help, I'm very confused..

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="nav-img" src="img/span-img.png" />
            </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CAREERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ADVERTISING</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar{
  background-color:#282828;
  height:83px;
  margin-top:0px;
}

.navbar .nav-img{
  height:77px;
  width:108px;
  margin-top:-12px;
}
```

Comment: It may be because of one of these classes collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse ..

Comment: I'm not getting your properly can you please post images ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `pull-right` for `div` instead of `ul` like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8903/)**

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse pull-right">
    <ul>..</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: He is no talking about this i think... Nice try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the default css according to you your convenience by making a file `custom.css`

Read more here :

https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

apply styling to the parent div instead of the ul element.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse pull-right">
```

or apply a css class to div and then style it inside your css file like:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse style"></div>
```

the css file say style.css will contain code as:

```
.style{
pull-right;
}
```

its easy to do as you can reuse it if needed somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You could try closing the `navbar-brand` div :

```
<div class="navbar-brand">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="nav-img" src="img/span-img.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

I had a similar problem and that seemed to work for me!

Answer (score -1):

Use this it will help you out

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="nav-img" src="img/span-img.png" />
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" style="width=100%;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CAREERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ADVERTISING</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: giving width 100% will make according to window with so that ul will then able to move right